# Issue with path and syncing in github actions

Tags: amazon-s3, github-actions

I have a GitHub Action workflow that syncs my GitHub repo with an AWS S3 bucket:

```
- name: Sync files repo and S3 bucket with the AWS CLI
  run: |
    aws s3 sync text/ s3://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}
```

This kinda worked when uploading my files from folder `text` to my s3 bucket but is not what I want. I want to download files from s3 to my folder in GitHub repo as well, so I tried this instead:

```
- name: Copy files to the test website with the AWS CLI
  run: |
    aws s3 sync s3://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }} text/
```

This seems to have downloaded all my files into folder `text` as indicated in my GitHub Actions logs shown below but the files are not there for some reason.

```
Run aws s3 sync s3://somename text/

Completed 3.0 KiB/18.0 MiB (24.1 KiB/s) with 10 file(s) remaining
download: s3://somename/f261f588-2286-417a-97e1-a688b623339f.yml to 
text/f261f588-2286-417a-97e1-a688b623339f.yml"
```

**Questions**

1. How should I sync my repo folders with my s3 bucket using the CLI commands?
2. If my folder is at a URL (https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo/tree/master/photo-art/text), how should I display the path for GitHub Actions?

This is my full yml file

**Full yml file as requested**

```
name: Sync S3 Object

on:
  push:
paths:
      - 'text/**'    
env:
  BUCKET_NAME : "somename"
  AWS_REGION : "us-east-1"

permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Sync to Amazon S3
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Configure AWS credentials from Dev account
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::acc-number:role/github-actions-role
        aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Copy files to the test website with the AWS CLI
      run: |
        aws s3 sync s3://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }} text/
    - name: Commit and push changes
      run: |
        git config --global user.name "somecompany"
        git config --global user.email "namer@name.com"
        git add -A
        git commit -m "update text"
    - name: Push changes
      uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

**Updated**
**Error message**

```
Run ad-m/github-push-action@master

Push to branch main
remote: Write access to repository not granted.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/somecompany/somename-website.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Invalid exit code: 128
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/ad-m/github-push-action/master/start.js:29:21)
```

Comment: What do you mean by that the files are downloaded but they are not in the repo? Have you verified with `git status` or `ls` commands? And, what do you mean by "**how should I display the path for GitHub Actions**"?

Comment: Also, please include your relevant workflow in your question e.g. checkout, AWS CLI setup, login, etc. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I added the additional info you requested. I am not sure how to verify with git status or ls as i am using only using the github browser. The folder is not populated with the files that ought to be downloaded. Uploading file from github folder to S3 bucket is working fine as i can see the file in my s3 bucket.

Comment: Sure, no problem. You can run `git status` and `ls` commands after sync is successful and check those in the GHA workflow run logs.

Comment: The files are not there. Do you have any idea why the history in GHA seem to have indicated it was downloaded but it cant be found?

Comment: According to [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command: "Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. **Recursively copies new and updated files from the source directory to the destination.** Only creates folders in the destination if they contain one or more files." Were there any new or updated/modified files? If not, this won't do anything. You can use `aws s3 cp` instead.